# Unable to remove env variable from .bash_profile

Tags: python, shell, pycharm, environ

I have a few problems regarding the use of `.bash_profile` and Pycharm. I am using mac OS X. I created a new project on pycharm with new environment using virtualenv with base interpreter `/usr/local/bin/python3.5`.

STEP 1:
I then accessed the .bash_profile from my mac OS terminal and exported 2 variables: `DB_USER` and `DB_PASS` as `my_db_user` and `my_db_pass` respectively.

STEP 2:
Using Pycharm, I imported os and then proceeded to print out the 2 variables using `os.environ.get()`. Running the .py file using pycharm (F10) returns `my_db_user` and `my_db_pass`.

As I decided to create 2 new variables `test user` and `test pass` in the virtual environment, I proceeded to activate my venv (`venv/bin/activate`) in the shell of pycharm. Then, I removed the changes I did in STEP 1.

However, running the .py using pycharm (F10) STILL returns `my_db_user` and `my_db_pass` instead of `test user` and `test pass` (I have already removed `my_db_user` and `my_db_pass` so I have no idea where it is coming from!). On top of that, when I run the python file on the shell using python test.py, it returns (None, None) instead of my desired `test user` and `test pass`.

I need help to sort this out so that `os.environ.get()` returns my desired output. One possible reason is that I might be confused on how pycharm, shell in pycharm and terminals are interacting. Please help thanks!

```
import os

user = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
password = os.environ.get('DB_PASS')

print(user,password)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read your post correctly, you have already cleared out the `.bash_profile` file, so what remains is just running

```
unset DB_USER DB_PASS
```

in each shell window that still has the environment variables.

Comment: also, check if the variables have been written to your ~/.bash_profile and if they have, remove them. then run: source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: it worked, thank you. If possible, I would like to know why using unset command is required on top of clearing of .bash_profile. And, is there a difference between nano .bash_profile and nano ~/.bash_profile?